# Pygame array; keeping list items constant

Tags: python

I have an array in python(pygame):

```
Grid=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

I have written a program that changes some of the values of the array to 1 if certain variables are true. How can I ensure that the first item and the last item in all 3 lists will always remain as 0?

Answer (score 2):

```
def ensureZeros(grid):
    for row in grid:
        row[0] = row[-1] = 0
```

You just need a function that sets the first and last item of each row to zero. Call this whenever you need to ensure that there are zeros in the correct places.